# How do I write code for countdown app in python PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am struggling to find any resources on the internet to help me with my code. I want my app to count down the amount of days left before the next holiday. Everything is displaying except the calculation for *amount of days left until next holiday* I need to code that part but don't know how...can anyone help or guide me.

The app looks like this:
TODAYS DATE IS DISPLAYED BELOW
*Calendar widget*

SELECT THE DATE OF NEXT HOLIDAY BELOW
*Calendar widget*

*command push button - calculate amount of days until next holiday*

*Empty QLabel* to display the date selected
*Empty Qlabel* to display the count down amount of days until next holiday

My .pyw code is:

```
import sys
from assignmenttwocal import *
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.computefare)
    
    def computefare(self):
        dateselected=self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        dateinstring=str(dateselected.toPyDate())

        self.ui.EnteredInfo.setText('Date of next holiday: '+dateinstring)
        
        
      
       self.ui.CompInfo.setText('Amount of days until next hoiday:')
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If your question is "how can I find how many days to xyz from today?", read the documentation about [`QDate.daysTo()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#daysTo).

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know if it works